# How to delete a window?

Tags: c++, qt

I used the following command to create and show a window:

```
QGCSettingsWidget* settings = new QGCSettingsWidget(this);//here this means the mainwindow
settings->show();
```

The constructor is like:

```
QGCSettingsWidget::QGCSettingsWidget(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags) :
    QDialog(parent, flags),
    mainWindow((MainWindow*)parent),
    ui(new Ui::QGCSettingsWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ....
    MAVLinkSettingsWidget* msettings = new MAVLinkSettingsWidget(mavlink, this);//set its parent to be this.
}
```

The deconstructor is:

```
QGCSettingsWidget::~QGCSettingsWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

However, I found that when I click the close button of the created window. Although the window disappear, the msettings is not destructed.
How could I make it properly deleted?

Comment: Is `msettings` declared as a member of the `QGCSettingsWidget` class?

Comment: Here is the [MAVLinkSettingsWidget](https://github.com/diydrones/apm_planner/blob/master/src/ui/MAVLinkSettingsWidget.cc). The second argument is `parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close a window it is not destroyed but hides if you didn't set an attribute `WA_DeleteOnClose`:

```
settings->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
settings->show();
```